# How to serialize a Map[CustomType, String] to JSON

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-json

Given the following `Enumeration`...

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

  type MyEnum = Value

  val Val1 = Value("val1")
  val Val2 = Value("val2")
  val Val3 = Value("val3")
} 

import MyEnum._
```

... and the following `Map`...

```
val m = Map(
  val1 -> "one",
  val2 -> "two",
  val3 -> "three"
)
```

... I need to transform `m` to JSON:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val js = Json.toJson(m)
```

The last statement doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't find a Json serializer for type `scala.collection.immutable.Map[MyEnum.Value,String]`.

Question: Since Play does provide a serializer for type `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]`, and my enumeration actually contains strings, is there a way to reuse the default JSON serializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The built-in `Reads` objects](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads$) don't define a `Reads` for a `Map` that's parametric in the key. You could do something like:

```
implicit def looserMapWrites[A <: AnyRef, B : Writes]: Writes[Map[A, B]] = Writes { o => 
  Json.toJson(o.map { case (key, value) => 
    key.toString -> value 
  })(Writes.mapWrites) 
}
```

And with your values above, you get:

```
scala> Json.toJson(m)(looserMapWrites)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"val1":"one","val2":"two","val3":"three"}
```

If you want to, you can tighten those bounds on `A` to make it not applicable to any `AnyRef`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a play.api.libs.json.Format for MyEnum.Value which translates your enum to and from a string representation. Such as the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

  type MyEnum = Value

  val Val1 = Value("val1")
  val Val2 = Value("val2")
  val Val3 = Value("val3")

  implicit val myEnumWrites = new Writes[Value]{
    def writes(o:Value)=JsString(o.toString)
  }
}
```

a more complete format (read and write) for MyEnum could look like

```
implicit val myEnumFormat = new Format[Value]{
  def writes(o:Value)=JsString(o.toString)
  def reads(json:JsValue):JsResult[Value]=json match {
    case JsString("val1") =>JsSuccess(Val1)
    case JsString("val2") =>JsSuccess(Val2)
    case JsString("val3") =>JsSuccess(Val3)
    case other => JsError(s"$other is not a valid value for MyEnum")
  }
}
```

Using Enumeration is not advised. It can generally be replaced by either a sealed trait and a hierarchy of case object/case classes OR by using a java enumeration.