# How do I avoid nested Array when serializing a Map with Play Writes?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

I am trying to serialize a map using the Json library from Play. I wrote my own Writes since there is none for Maps.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json._

object NestedArray extends App {
  val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")

  implicit val mWrites = new Writes[Map[Int, String]] {
    def writes(m: Map[Int, String]) = arr(
      m.keys.map(k => {
        obj("key" -> k.toString,
          "value" -> m(k)
        )
      })
    )
  }

  val j = toJson[Map[Int, String]](m)
  println(prettyPrint(j))
}
```

The output is this:

```
[ [ {
  "key" : "1",
  "value" : "one"
}, {
  "key" : "2",
  "value" : "two"
} ] ]
```

As you can see there are two pairs of [ ] around the items. When I use a Wrapper class around the map I only get one pair of [ ].

```
case class Wrap(m: Map[Int, String])
val w = new Wrap(m)

implicit val wrapWrites = new Writes[Wrap] {
  def writes(w: Wrap) = obj(
    "m" -> w.m.keys.map(k => {
      obj("key" -> k.toString,
        "value" -> w.m(k)
      )
    })
  )
}

val j2 = toJson[Wrap](w)
println(prettyPrint(j2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "m" : [ {
    "key" : "1",
    "value" : "one"
  }, {
    "key" : "2",
    "value" : "two"
  } ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that without a wrapper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.arr` makes a JSON array from it's argument list. Since the first argument is itself a sequence, the result is a sequence of a sequence.

E.g.

```
scala> Json.arr(1,2,3)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [1,2,3]

scala> Json.arr(List(1,2,3))
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [[1,2,3]]
```

Removing the call to `arr` and converting the Iterable directly to JSON using toJson removes the nested array

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json._

object NestedArray extends App {
  val m: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")

  implicit val mWrites = new Writes[Map[Int, String]] {
    def writes(m: Map[Int, String]): JsValue = 
      Json.toJson(m.keys.map(k => {
        obj("key" -> k.toString,
          "value" -> m(k)
        )
      }))
  }

  val j = toJson[Map[Int, String]](m)
  println(prettyPrint(j))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not think about using toJson there. I was only obj and arr came to my mind.

Comment: Same question for me, I wanted to cast the field to an JSArray. With that solution, you cast it to a generic JsValue.

Answer (score 0):

Play does provide a `Writes[Map[String, _]]`, which you can probably adapt for your uses. It seems unnecessary to create structure to represent a sequence of key-value pairs, when that's what a JSON object *is* already. Please see my answer to a similar question: [How to serialize a Map[CustomType, String] to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897921/how-to-serialize-a-mapcustomtype-string-to-json/25904606#25904606)